# typeof extend tutorial, confused, please help me understand

Tags: jquery, html, json

Please, I am having trouble digesting some code block and I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with one line as I am really confused. I have no one else to ask!!!!!

Here is the code breakdown:

```
<div id="log"></div> <!-- This is just a container div for the result -->

<script>

//Declare first object, object literal notation:

var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: { weight: 52, price: 100 },
  cherry: 97
};

//Declare Second object, object literal notation:

var object2 = {
  banana: { price: 200 },
  durian: 100
};

// Merge object2 into object1
$.extend( object1, object2 );

//This is were I am confused, why test for **typeof JSON**?
//Won't it always return "object"? My understanding is that JSON here is just a keyword,
//so typeof JSON will always return object, so of what use is it?

var printObj = typeof JSON !== "undefined" ? JSON.stringify : function( obj ) {
  var arr = [];
  $.each( obj, function( key, val ) {
    var next = key + ": ";
    next += $.isPlainObject( val ) ? printObj( val ) : val;
    arr.push( next );
  });
  return "{ " +  arr.join( ", " ) + " }";
};

//Here they called printObj as a function passing object1, but how is **object 1** being used,
//when the first statement in printObj is typef JSON?

$( "#log" ).append( printObj( object1 ));

</script>
```

So in essence I am having trouble understanding how the conditional **typeof JSON** is of any use, since it always returns "object". Also I am having trouble understanding the call **printObj(object1)** and how the argument **object1** fits in with **printObj** when the first thing there is **typeof JSON**.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much, yes, `JSON` will always exist - at least nowadays. But it isn't a keyword - it is a built-in object in JavaScript, the same as numbers and strings.

You can see at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Browser_compatibility) that older browsers do not support it, e.g. IE7, Safari 3. So either it is an old piece of code or it is trying to support older browsers.

The point of `printObj` is that it stores a reference to a function which takes an object and returns a string in JSON format. So the code is saying if the object `JSON` exists, then store a reference to `JSON.stringify` in `printObj`. Otherwise store a reference to the function inside it.

This means that when you then call `printObj(object1)`, you are actually calling `JSON.stringify(object1)`.

Comment: Woohoo! Thank you so much for that, it makes soooo much sense now. I was just stuck on typeof JSON, but with the explanation you gave for browser support, it really puts everything in perspective and I can see why they test for it.